# Extract result from statistical test into separate columns

Tags: r

I am trying to split into different columns the information shown in one column that contains the result of a statistical test (a list).

Creating a dataset:

```
a <- c(1:10) 

b <- c(11:20) 

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a, b))
```

Creating column with test result:

```
df$trend <- apply(df, 1, MannKendall)
```

The result that I want is:

[image]

```
tau <- c(1.00, 1.00) 

p_value <- c(8.31, 8.31)

df <- cbind(df, tau)

df <- cbind(df, p_value)

df
```

This is the result that I want, of course I have made it manually just to show how it would look

I have tried: `df %>% unnest_wider(trend)` without any luck.

I would like to separate the information shown in the trend column into different columns.

Comment: What is `MannKendall`? If it's not built into base R or an R package, can you provide it?

Comment: Please add the packages necessary to run functions `MannKendall` and `unnest_wider`, to make your post self-contained.

Comment: Oh, yes I am sorry, library(tidyr) for unnest_wider, and library(Kendall) for Mann Kedall function.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is from `Kendall` package, we can use

```
library(Kendall)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
   mutate(out = list(MannKendall(cur_data())[c("tau", "sl")])) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   unnest_wider(out, names_sep = "_") %>%
   rename_with( ~ c("tau", "p-value"), starts_with("out_"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 12
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   tau `p-value`
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10     1 0.0000831
2    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20     1 0.0000831
```